# Can Debezium ensure all events from the same transaction are published at the same time?

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I'm starting to explore the use of change data capture to convert the database changes from a legacy and commercial application (which I cannot modify) into events that could be consumed by other systems. Simplifying my real case, let's say that there will be two tables involved, `order` with the order header details and `order_line` with the details of each of the products requested.

My current understanding is that events from the two tables will be published into two different kafka topics and I should aggregate them using kafka-streams or ksql. I've seen there are different options to define the window that will be used to select all the events that are related, however it is not clear for me how I could be sure all the events coming from the same database transaction are already in the topic, so I do not miss any of them.

Is Debezium able to ensure this (all events from same transaction are published) or it could happen that, for example, Debezium crashes while publishing the events and only part of the ones generated by the same transaction are in Kafka?

If so, what's the recommended approach to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debezium stores the positions of transaction logs that it reads completely in Kafka and it uses these positions to resume its work on any crash or other situation like this also in other situations that may happen sometimes and in this situation the debezium loss it's position, it will restore it by reading the snapshot of database again!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get the part of keeping the position in kafka to being able to resume. What I'd like to confirm (let me know if it was not well expressed in the question) is what I will find in the topic in kafka in the following scenario: after comiting a transaction that inserts 3 rows, debezium starts to generate the events and it crashes (for whatever reason) while generating the one for the second row; I would expect that no event appears in the topic until the whole transaction has been processed however I guess I will find the event for the 1st row only. Could you confirm?

Comment: Right, You will find an event for the first row only. I can relate why you don't want the first event but Debezium works on bin logs it doesn't consider commits per se.

Comment: For the record, I've found that current development version (see announcement here: https://debezium.io/blog/2020/02/11/debezium-1-1-beta1-released/#transaction_markers) added the concept of transaction markers which I think it could be used for my use case. I need time to give it a try.